# Proving E(X|X<Y) that is less than or equal to EX where X and Y are independent random variables

Tags: inequality, random-variables, conditional-expectation, independence

I would like to prove that E(X |X< Y) <= EX where X and Y are independent random variables. It's easy to prove the inequality when Y is a constant, but what about when Y is only independent from X? We assume that  X,Y have means and P(X< Y)>0.

Comment: The assumption is that P(X<Y)>0.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that $EXI_{X<t} \leq (EX) P(X<t)$ for all $t$ you can just integrate this w.r.t the distribution of $Y$. Fubini's Theorem gives you $EXI_{X<Y} \leq (EX) P(X<Y)$.

Comment: Thank you sir. When do we apply the independency?

Comment: @DisjointUnion $E(XI_{X<Y})=\int E(XI_{X<t})dF_Y(t)$ and $P(X<Y)=\int P(X<t)dF_Y(t)$. These are valid because of independence.